# Custom choropleth map with states grouped into territories

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, states, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choropleth map that basically groups states into sales territories.  For example: Georgia, Florida, and Alabama would be treated as one territory called Southeast.

It seems like I should be able to use the existing state shapefile data from map_data("state") to create a new shapefile with these territories.

But I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

---

Thanks for the help guys.  Let me try to add some code to explain.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(plyr)
library(grid)

#load us state map data
us_state_map = map_data("state");

#map each state to a division
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("connecticut", "maine", "massachusetts", "new hampshire", "rhode island", "vermont")] <- "D1"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("new jersey","new york","puerto rico","virgin islands")] <- "D2"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("delaware","district of columbia","maryland","pennsylvania","virginia","west virginia")] <- "D3"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("alabama","florida","georgia","kentucky","mississippi","north carolina","south carolina","tennessee")] <- "D4"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("illinois","indiana","michigan","minnesota","ohio","wisconsin")] <- "D5"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("arkansas","louisiana","new mexico","oklahoma","texas")] <- "D6"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("iowa","kansas","missouri","nebraska")] <- "D7"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("colorado","montana","north dakota","south dakota","utah","wyoming")] <- "D8"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("arizona","california","hawaii","nevada")] <- "D9"
us_state_map$division[us_state_map$region %in% c("alaska","idaho","oregon","washington")] <- "D10"

#create a dummy variable that counts the number of states in each division
divisions.subtotal <- ddply(us_state_map, .(division), summarize, NumberOfStates=length(unique(region)))

#merge our dummy data back into the map data table
us_state_map.mod <- merge(x=us_state_map, y=divisions.subtotal, all.x=TRUE, by.x="division", by.y="division")
us_state_map.mod = arrange(us_state_map.mod, order);
us_state_map.mod$division = as.factor(us_state_map.mod$division)

#plot a map of each division
map <- ggplot() 
map = map + geom_polygon(data=us_state_map.mod, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=division))
map

#using these division boundaries, how do i plot the NumberOfStates variable for each Division
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the shape file, why not just build a function that takes in a dataframe in terms of your sales territories and spits out a dataframe in terms of states suitable for plotting? You could probably pull this off with a dataframe linking states to sales regions and a simple call to `merge`

Comment: Depending on what your data looks like, try `rgeos::gUnion`.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me the right direction.  I've added some code that will help explain what I'm working on.  I can't tell if all the code pasted in or not though - it should end with a call to ggplot() and then a comment...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you still need an answer or not, but I would suggest using the maps library:

```
map("usa")

map("state",regions=c("connecticut", "maine", "massachusetts", 
    "new hampshire", "rhode island","vermont"),interior=F,boundary=T,add=T)
```

Then using `col= specifications` to shade different levels for each region. It's a little tedious, but it does create the regions.